# Overriding Constructor of BCL class in Generated Code

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, swagger, x509certificate, .net-4.6

I have some code that was generated by NSwagStudio.  Not that that really matters as this could apply to any generated code.  It's really a matter of not wanting to manipulate the generated code in case it ever has to be regenerated due to API, schema change, etc.  At any rate I have some code that looks like this

```
var client_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
```

This isn't shared by the generated class.  It's new'd up in every method.  Problem is I can't seem to find a way to have it send client certificates to a server without manipulating the generated code and replacing the above line with

```
var x509Store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var x509Certificate = x509Store.Certificates.Find(
    X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyClientCertName", true
    )[0];
var webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
webRequestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate);
var client_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
```

This has to be done in every method that calls the web service.  Not a whole lot but enough to be annoying.  Also not to mention that me or another developer has to remember to modify this if the code is ever regenerated.

I've wracked my brain around possible solutions such as an extension constructor for the System.Net.HttpClient; some how doing something in a partial class or wrapper class.  I'm not really coming up with any decent solutions that are possible or work.

I don't have a lot of experience with Dependency Injection but maybe this is a candidate for it?  Somehow if I could tell .NET that hey I have this client certificate and any time you make a call to service X I always want you to pass it along.  I could do this if I stored my handler and somehow told the compiler to always pass it along to the constructor if the parameter less constructor is used.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Swagger, but I can tell you that Dependency Injection is not magic and more importantly, it is not meant for *runtime configuration* such as this - it is meant to compose the application at startup.

You should look for a way within Swagger to either generate the exact code you need (recommended) or hook into some event just after the code is generated so you can automate the process of altering the generated code. The [T4 template](https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/wiki/T4) option looks promising.